# pthread_join function kill the thread after execution or we need to call pthread_cancel/pthread_exit?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

`pthread_join()` function kill the thread after execution or we need to call `pthread_cancel()`/`pthread_exit()`?

I am calling `pthread_cancel()`/`pthread_kill()` which is returning 3 ie no thread attached with thread_id.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void * run (void *);

int main() {
pthread_t p1, p2;
int a = 9;
printf("%d\n", pthread_create(&p1, NULL, &run, (void*)&p1));
printf("%d\n", pthread_create(&p2, NULL, &run, (void*)&p2));

printf("%d\n", pthread_join(p1, NULL));
//usleep(1000);
printf("%d\n", pthread_join(p2, NULL));

printf("before exit\n");
printf("%d\n", pthread_cancel(p1));
printf("after exit\n");
printf("%d\n", pthread_cancel(p2));
printf("both thread exited\n");

printf("%d\n", pthread_join(p1, NULL));
printf("%d\n", pthread_join(p2, NULL));
printf("terminated\n");

printf("%d\n", pthread_kill(p1, 0));
printf("%d\n", pthread_kill(p2, 0));
printf("ext\n");

printf("%d\n", pthread_join(p1, NULL));
printf("%d\n", pthread_join(p2, NULL));
printf("jion\n");

return 0;
}

void *run (void *p) {

int *i = (int*)p;
printf("created i = %d\n", *i);
}
```

This is the code i am using. in this pthread_cancel on wards all function returning 3 which means thread is being already killed.

Comment: `pthread_join()` does not kill the thread but waits for the thread to complete.

Comment: pthread_join will wait for completion of specified thred, so if function call is returned it means that thread is terminated. While canel/kill functions will terminate specified thread

Comment: Can you show us some code please? This should include how you create the thread and how you kill the thread. The actual thread itself is probably not needed.

Comment: pthread_join waits for which thread to complete, current running thread or any other there already running presently ?

Comment: show some code :). It will be easier to point out your error.

Comment: From `printf("before exit\n");` to `printf("jion\n");` unnecessary code. you are trying to kill a dead snake :)

Comment: @rjayavrp: threads are snakes?  That would imply they are sneaky and dangerous to handle if you don't know what you are doing.  Oh, wait...

Answer (score 7):

`pthread_join` does not kill the thread, it waits for the thread to complete.  If you want to kill a thread then use `pthread_kill`.  But that has to be done *before* `pthread_join`, otherwise the thread has already exited.

`pthread_cancel` requests that the thread teminate at the next cancellation point, and is probably safer than using `pthread_kill`.

`pthread_exit` exits the current thread.

Comment: can I call pthread_cancel in main function at the end of code before return ?

Comment: @Anand: Yes, but you should still use `pthread_join` to sync the threads.  If you exit `main` while a thread is running you have no idea what it is doing at the time.

Answer (score 0):

After `pthread_join()` Add

```
/* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
```

For more details pls refer [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

pthread_join() is used to make the main() thread wait till all the threads completes it's execution. Control reaches the pthread_join(), when that particular thread completes it's execution. 
So if you try to cancel/kill that particular thread, error will be returned.

**Sample Code**

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define NUM_THREADS 4

    void *BusyWork(void *t)
    {
       int i;
       long tid;
       tid = (long)t;
       printf("Thread %ld starting...\n",tid);
       pthread_exit((void*) t);                 //Exits that current thread.
    }

    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       pthread_t thread[NUM_THREADS];
       int rc;
       long t;
       void *status;

       for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) {
          printf("Main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
          rc = pthread_create(&thread[t], NULL, BusyWork, (void *)t); 
          if (rc) {
             printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
             exit(-1);
             }
          }

      /* Wait for completion */
       for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) {
          rc = pthread_join(thread[t], &status);
          if (rc) {
             printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
             exit(-1);
             }
printf("Main: completed join with thread %ld having a status of %ld\n",t,(long)status);
          }

    printf("Main: program completed. Exiting.\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL); // Exits main thread.
    }
```

For @Joachim Pileborg

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4

void *BusyWork(void *t)
{
   int i;
   long tid;
   tid = (long)t;

   printf("Thread %ld starting...\n",tid);

   for(i = 0; i <10000000; i++)
        printf("\n Thread: %ld,  %d", tid, i);

   pthread_exit((void*) t);                 //Exits that current thread.
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t thread[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   void *status;

   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) {
      printf("Main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&thread[t], NULL, BusyWork, (void *)t);
      if (rc) {
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
         }
      }

//printf("Main: program completed. Exiting.\n");
pthread_exit(NULL); // Exits main thread(work will be done).
//return 0;//( Threads will exit once main exits.)
}
```

Comment: `pthread_join` is used in the _parent_ thread to wait for the _created_ thread. The _created_ thread should call `pthread_exit` (or just return from the thread function) and **not** the _parent_ thread.

Comment: yes. pthread_exit(NULL) at main as well as all the thread functions.

Comment: Actually, you should not exit the main thread (i.e. the one started by running your `main` function) with `pthread_exit`. Instead to exit the _process_ you should either return from `main` or use the `exit` function.

Comment: ok.. suppose all thread should run after finishing `main` (no pthread_join in this scenario). I will use pthread_exit(NULL) right?

Comment: Still no, then you make your threads _detached_. Like I said, don't use `pthread_exit` to exit from the `main` function.

Comment: Thanks for info. Im not clear why pthread_exit should not be used in main(). Anyway I google it and comeback to SO then :).

Comment: When I am calling pthread_exit or pthread_cancel then it is returning error. What does that error mean ?

Comment: Actually, I just check the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html) and using `pthread_exit` in the main thread is the same as calling `exit`. However, it's not as clear as using `exit` or just plain returning, which is the reason I kind of misunderstood it. It will work, but it will also make people confused, which is a good a reason as any to not use it.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, pls look at my example. use of `return` makes issue for attached threads(attached by default).

Comment: Yes, but it's still easy to misunderstand and is not explicit, while detaching the threads that needs to continue running is explicit.

Comment: @Anand: have you tried reading the man pages for any of this?  RTFM. *If successful, the pthread_cancel() function returns zero. Otherwise, an error number is returned to indicate the error.*

Answer (score 0):

Some context would be nice... but if you're just waiting for a thread (presumably you only have one you care about) to terminate/return, then pthread_join is good enough.

> The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by thread
>   to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated, then pthread_join() returns
>   immediately.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html

Check the man page for usage/warnings.